# Parameterized Query in C#

Tags: c#

How will I make this not prone to SQL injection? These codes are to insert data to database, and alot says that in this format it is prone to SQL injection.

```
private void DBConn()
{
    string ConString = "datasource = localhost; Username = root; Password=; database = logbook";
    MySqlConnection DBConnnect = new MySqlConnection(ConString);
    try
    {
        DBConnnect.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = DBConnnect.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into tbl_data (Student_Number, Name, Strand, Section) values('"+textBox1.Text+"', '"+textBox2.Text+"', '"+textBox3.Text+"', '"+textBox4.Text+"')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DBConnnect.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Student registered successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: please note, this is an *sql injection attack* waiting to happen, never pass user input into a query like this

Comment: You may wish to consider using Dapper or the like since they make it relatively easy to avoid SQL Injection issues.

Answer (score 3):

Like this...

```
private void DBConn()
{
    string ConString = "datasource = localhost; Username = root; Password=; database = logbook";
    MySqlConnection DBConnnect = new MySqlConnection(ConString);
    try
    {
        DBConnnect.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = DBConnnect.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into tbl_data (Student_Number, Name, Strand, Section) values(@student_number, @name, @strand, @section)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("student_number", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", textBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("strand", textBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("section", textBox4.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DBConnnect.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Student registered successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: But how will I do it with login form? If its not add?         "select * FROM tbl_enduser where Username = '" + lgUsername.Text + "' and Password = '" + lgPassword.Text + "' "       can that be converted to parameterized one?

Comment: @Larry I'd do it the same way.  But one suggestion if you are working with passwords I'd read up on the following.... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/pwdcompare-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/pwdencrypt-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15.  Do not store unencrypted passwords in a database.

Answer (score 0):

The official [SqlCommand.Parameters Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8) has everything you need.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tablename(column1,column2,column3) VALUES(@column1,@column2,@column3)
```

There is some discussion about risks of `AddWithValue` so you may want to opt for the Add(...).Value approach.

```
command.Parameters.Add("@column1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = x;
command.Parameters.Add("@column2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = y;
command.Parameters.Add("@column3", SqlDbType.Int).Value = z;
```

---

You should be using the `using` statement.

```
var commandText = "INSERT INTO tablename(column1,column2,column3) VALUES(@column1,@column2,@column3)

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);

    command.Parameters.Add("@column1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = x;
    command.Parameters.Add("@column2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = y;
    command.Parameters.Add("@column3", SqlDbType.Int).Value = z;
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        Int32 rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note this question is MySQL, not SQL.